# Getting the day for each week missing 31st of the month

Tags: java

I am calculating the same day for each week:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
        
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate startLocalDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-01-03");
        LocalDate endLocalDate = startLocalDate.withDayOfMonth(startLocalDate.getMonth().length(startLocalDate.isLeapYear()));
        int startDayOfWeek = startLocalDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        List<LocalDate> listOfDays = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
            for (LocalDate date = startLocalDate; date.isBefore(endLocalDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
            if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() == startDayOfWeek) {
                listOfDays .add(date);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listOfDays);
    }
}
```

I am getting:

```
[2023-01-03, 2023-01-10, 2023-01-17, 2023-01-24]
```

but I expected to get:

```
[2023-01-03, 2023-01-10, 2023-01-17, 2023-01-24, 2023-01-31]
```

31st is missing.

Comment: Well, `date.isBefore(endLocalDate)` basically states you're only interested in dates that are _before_ the last day of the month so you basically exclude the 31st from the loop. Try `!date.isAfter(endLocalDate)` instead - or just use a numeric loop `for(int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++) ` in combination with `date = startLocalDate.plusDays(i)`.

Comment: Btw, you could also try to optimize the loop and once you have the first "start of week" day, you could add 7 until the (correct) end condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fencepost error. Your loop's 'end condition' is:

If the `date` variable is **no longer** before `endDate`, stop right now.

`for (init; cond; incr) code;`

is identical to:

```
init;
while (cond) {
  code;
  incr;
}
```

That means that once `date` is updated by the `for` increment (`date = date.plusDays(1)`), that new date is immediately checked with the condition (is that still BEFORE `endDate`), and the loop aborts then and there if that fails to hold.

Thus, your code goes for 31st of january and aborts the loop on the spot, it never gets handled.

Presumably, you want, for condition, not `date.isBefore(endDate)`, but `!date.isAfter(endLocalDate)`. To ensure that 31st of jan *IS* handled.

Alternatively, keep it as is, but edit your end date. This simplifies the calculation for end date in passing:

```
LocalDate endLocalDate = startLocalDate.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1);
```

Now `endLocalDate` is feb 1st, and that means jan 31st is still processed, and then feb 1st causes the loop to stop.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876760/642706) is correct and smart.

## Streams

In addition, FYI, streams make such work easier.

The [`LocalDate#datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)) methods generate a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of `LocalDate` objects. We can filter those for a match on our desired day-of-week.

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2023-01-03" );
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = start.getDayOfWeek();
LocalDate stop = start.withDayOfMonth( 1 ).plusMonths( 1 ); // Using Half-Open approach, running up to but not including first day of following month. End date is *exclusive* while the start date is *inclusive*. 

List < LocalDate > datesInSameMonthWithSameDayOfWeek =
        start
                .datesUntil( stop )
                .filter(
                        date -> date.getDayOfWeek().equals( dayOfWeek )
                )
                .toList()
;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/zEQVIA).

> [2023-01-03, 2023-01-10, 2023-01-17, 2023-01-24, 2023-01-31]

---

We *might* gain some efficiency by using the other [`datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.Period)) method taking a `step` argument. But I would not bother for such a small amount of data as this.

Comment: Great addition!